# Inserting an option in a selected element, before the selected one, breaks blazor binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, binding, blazor

Consider the following Blazor component:

```
@page "/select-repro"

<select @bind="selectedItem">
    @foreach (string item in items)
    {
        <option value="@item">@item</option>
    }
</select>
<button type="button" @onclick="InsertItem">Insert Item</button>

@code
{
    private readonly List<string> items = new() { "A", "B", "C" };
    private string selectedItem = "B";

    private void InsertItem()
    {
        items.Insert(0, "X");
    }
}
```

When the button is clicked, the selected option changes from `B` to `A`.
I do not understand why this change happens. The value of `selectedItem` does not change.

If the new item is inserted AFTER the current selection (with `items.Add("X")`), then the selection will not change.

Is this the expected behavior? How can I keep the same value selected?

Comment: Use @key `<option @key=item value="@item">@item</option>`

Comment: Thanks, this work. But why do we have to do that?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/element-component-model-relationships?view=aspnetcore-7.0#when-to-use-key